Is there a mathematical expression linking effort required to lift a weight and the weight value?
I have no idea if this is the right forum but here we go
I'm basically wondering if there is a math expression linking the amount of effort required to lift a weight at the gym, and the value of the weight
I know there is an expression for work performed
$W = F\Delta d = ma\Delta d$
However, it is linear with respect to mass. If I lift a weight of $x$kg at the gym for 10 reps, and I increase the weight to $10x$kg, I am unable to do even a single rep. So the relationship I am looking for is non-linear with respect to mass.
In essence I want to be able to answer a question of the form:
"I can do 10 reps with $x$ weight, what is the formula to find the weight at which I can do only 5 reps?"

This seems more like a fitness question than a biology one.

I saw this as a kinesiology question... not sure where to post

Pretty sure that Bryan is referring to  our [fitness.se] site, but be sure to take their tour, read their help centre and delete this version here before posting.
